# How to disable intellisense tooltip in SQL Management Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, envdte, vs-extensibility

I am building and addin that will provide richer info that SQL Management Studio tooltip. My tooltip is shown but always behind intellisense's tooltip. Is there a way to disable Intellisenses tooltips in SQL 2012 and 2008? I've tried with Forcing window to foreground with native code but with no luck. Also tried with SetWindowPos and that didn't provide any results.

Comment: For SQL SERVER Mgmt Studio from Toolbar Toggle `Query >> Intellisense Enabled`.

Comment: Yes, but I would still like to have SQL Srv Mgmt Studio Intellisense enabled with rest of the functionality like it's syntax checker and complete.